# How do I change datepicker end date based on start date by 1 year

Tags: javascript

I have a standard datepicker with a Start and End date. I want the End date to increase by 1 year based on what the user selects as the start date.

Here is my Javascript code.

```
$("#startDate").on("change", function (e) {
  $("#endDate").val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to create a date object from the start input value and increment the year by one,
afterward, you can format and feed the modified date back in the endDate input:

```js
$("#startDate").on("change", function(e) {
  var d = new Date($(this).val())
  d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 1)

  $("#endDate").val(d.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>
    start
  </p>
  <input type='date' id='startDate' placeholder='start' />
</div>


<div>
  <p>
    end
  </p>
  <input type='date' id='endDate'  />
</div>
```